# Spring Kafka Consume JsonNode objects

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a service that is producing Kafka messages with a payload of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`. When I consume this message I want it to be serialized into a POJO, but I'm getting the following message:

> IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header
>   'kafka_receivedMessageKey'. Expected [class com.example.Person] but
>   actual type is [class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode]

How do I configure either the producer or the consumer parts to work as I intend it to?

I think these are the approaches I can take:

Kafka Consumer should ignore `__Key_TypeId__` if it is a subclass of `JsonNode`

**OR**

Kafka Producer should produce a message without `__Key_TypeId__` header if it is a subclass of `JsonNode`

But how do I implement either of these approaches? Or is there another option?

Comment: Why your producer can't send a `com.example.Person` instead of low-level `JsonNode`? It is going to be serialized into a JSON properly and that type will dictate for the consumer what to do with `byte[]` in the network package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes).

You can either set `JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` to `false` on the producer or `JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` to false on the consumer.